# Returning a dataframe in python function

Tags: python-3.x, function, dataframe, return

I am trying to create and return a data frame from a Python function

```
def create_df():
    data = {'state': ['Ohio','Ohio','Ohio','Nevada','Nevada'],
           'year': [2000,2001,2002,2001,2002],
           'pop': [1.5,1.7,3.6,2.4,2.9]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    return df
create_df()
df
```

I get an error that saying that `df` is not defined. If I replace `return` with `print` I get print of the data frame correctly. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: `df` is a local variable. You need to assign the result like `df = create_df()`.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Wwhen you call `create_df()`, Python calls the function but doesn't save the result in any variable. That is why you got the error.

Assign the result of `create_df()` to a new variable `df` like this:

```
df = create_df()
df
```

Answer (score 18):

I'm kind of late here, but what about creating a global variable within the function?  It should save a step for you.

```
def create_df():

    global df

    data = {
    'state': ['Ohio','Ohio','Ohio','Nevada','Nevada'],
    'year': [2000,2001,2002,2001,2002],
    'pop': [1.5,1.7,3.6,2.4,2.9]
    }

    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Then when you run create_df(), you'll be able to just use df.

Of course, be careful in your naming strategy if you have a large program so that the value of df doesn't change as various functions execute.

EDIT: I noticed I got some points for this.  Here's another (probably worse) way to do this using exec. This also allows for multiple dataframes to be created, if desired.

```
import pandas as pd

def create_df():
    data = {'state': ['Ohio','Ohio','Ohio','Nevada','Nevada'],
           'year': [2000,2001,2002,2001,2002],
           'pop': [1.5,1.7,3.6,2.4,2.9]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    return df

### We'll create three dataframes for an example
for i in range(3):
    exec(f'df_{i} = create_df()')
```

Then, you can test them out:

Input: `df_0`

Output:

```
    state  year  pop
0    Ohio  2000  1.5
1    Ohio  2001  1.7
2    Ohio  2002  3.6
3  Nevada  2001  2.4
4  Nevada  2002  2.9
```

Input: `df_1`

Output:

```
    state  year  pop
0    Ohio  2000  1.5
1    Ohio  2001  1.7
2    Ohio  2002  3.6
3  Nevada  2001  2.4
4  Nevada  2002  2.9
```

Etc.

Comment: I would advise against the use of global variables for a python beginner, your namespace can get messy very quick

Answer (score 2):

**Function explicitly returns two DataFrames:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def return_2DF():

    date = pd.date_range('today', periods=20)
    DF1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(20, 2), index=date, columns=list('xyz'))

    DF2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(20, 4), index=date, columns='A B C D'.split())

    return DF1, DF2
```

**Calling and returning two data frame**

```
one, two = return_2DF()
```

Comment: exactly what I needed!!

Comment: This worked well for me. Thanks for the info

Answer (score 2):

You can return dataframe from a function by making a copy of the dataframe like

```
def my_function(dataframe):
  my_df=dataframe.copy()
  my_df=my_df.drop(0)
  return(my_df)

new_df=my_function(old_df)
print(type(new_df))
```

Output: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

Answer (score 0):

```
Dataframe_object.copy()
```

A deep copy needs to be performed to avoid issues of one dataframe being the reference to another dataframe. This is most crucial when you have a function in a module (or a separate file) returning a dataframe. If you don't do return DataFrame_object.copy(), it will only return a reference to the dataframe created in the function.\

If you are using a function in the same file, you might not even realize this issue of deep copy / shallow copy if you are using a global variable in the function.

Answer (score 0):

I have come across this issue before but solved it really easily by setting a variable outside the function to be the output of the function.

```
def create_df():
    data = {'state': ['Ohio','Ohio','Ohio','Nevada','Nevada'],
           'year': [2000,2001,2002,2001,2002],
           'pop': [1.5,1.7,3.6,2.4,2.9]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    return df

df = create_df()
```

Comment: Instead of posting another answer with the same solution, consider vote up when you reach 15+ reputation points.